# using maximum (or single) value of accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

is there a way to get  maximum value or single value of accelerometer output in subjected time frame?
I tried to use Max_Value or Math.  object but couldnt find any way.Also tried to use For and If clauses but couldnt managed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code so that we can help you.

Comment: thank you , actually there is no specific code  exists. my question if there is a way to just take maximum value of sensor output for some period of time or just taking specific range of value for some period of time.

Comment: "         
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    
     float[] values = event.values;
     float x = values[0];
      float y = values[1];
      float z = values[2];
     double d1=  ( (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z) )) ;
     double d2= ( (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z) )) ;
     
      float total =  (float) (Math.max(d1, d2));
      
    //float total = Float.MAX_VALUE total
   

        String total1=Float.toString((long) total);
            
     ( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(total1) ;
    }        "